# Youtube downloader that can use the youtube.com/user/userxxxx url

Tags: windows-7, windows, video, youtube

I am trying to find a youtube downloader that **allows to put in the url youtube.com/user/userxxx**, then presents me with a list of all the videos of userxxx so that I can select the videos I am interested in and download them. This allows me for example to easily download lots of videos from a specific channel, instead of having to copy/paste individual links like it is done in many downloaders.

Up till now I have been using the dvdvideosoft.com free youtube downloader and it works well. However, with their latest version of the downloader, they have started to use the opencandy adware stuff when installing the software. I do not like this opencandy stuf at all, as it happens during install time when the app has admin rights. Also see this article http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2677.

I have been looking at many downloaders yesterday (eg xVideoservicethief, freemake video downloader, imtoo download youtube video, zillatube, cliparchiver, xilisoft online video downloader, ashampoo clipfinder,..etc) but none seem to offer this functionality. The only one that indicated it supported it, was the biennesoft youtube downloader. However, when I tried it out, it did not work at all.

Does anyone know of an alternative downloader that has such a feature?

Comment: Jdownloader2 does everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your question and decided I could use a piece of software like that too. So I started looking around and here is what I found.

Look at [this](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/36290/tubulator) and see if there is a windows version.

[Internet Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) is the software I currently use, it just inserts a link into the browser. It doesn't really answer your question but I find it useful.

I'll let you know if I find anything else.

Comment: I have found a windows version on http://tubulatorapp.com/. I installed the latest beta version 0.92.2 and tried out putting in a user channel url. Pros:yes it does work well. Cons: I find the interface of the dvdvideosoft software much faster for selecting large numbers of videos. This beta does not support HD videos yet. Once it reaches v1, it becomes shareware. I will keep a watch on this software to see how it develops. Thanks.

Comment: From @Zumteufel: Just an update regarding the Tubulator application mentioned above (http://tubulatorapp.com/). It has since been rewritten from scratch in C++ (available for both Mac OS and Windows), and now supports batch downloads from entire user uploads, favorites, playlists.  (Disclaimer: I am the author of the application).